# How to make an id unique on page with JSF composite components?

Tags: javascript, jsf-2, java-ee-6, composite-component

I am making a component for the Javascript charting library called flot.

```
<cc:interface>        
    <cc:attribute name="data" required="true" /> 
</cc:interface>

<cc:implementation>
    <div id="placeholder" style="width:600px;height:300px;"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
        //<![CDATA[
    $(function () {       
        
      var d1 = [#{cc.attrs.data}];     

        $.plot($("#placeholder"), [ d1 ]);

    });
    //]]>
    </script>
</cc:implementation>
```

This is the small amount of code I have so far.  The problem I have is how would I make that div tag randomly generate on a page so that I can output multiple charts.  Obviously it won't do that in the current state.  I would need to pass the value into the javascript function to.

I know I can just create another attribute with id required and the user would have to specify the id, but I've noticed on a lot of components that the id is not required.  It seems in heavy ajax/javascript libraries like primefaces and icefaces that the ids are random some how.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can get the composite component's own ID by `#{cc.id}`. So to ensure uniqueness, just do:

```
<div id="#{cc.id}_placeholder" style="width:600px;height:300px;"></div>
```

and

```
$.plot($("##{cc.id}_placeholder"), [ d1 ]);
```

JSF will autogenerate one if you don't specify any `id` attribute on the component. E.g.

```
<my:plot id="foo">
```

Here `foo` will be used as `#{cc.id}` in the composite component implementation.

Comment: There we go.  Thanks.  I was adding the id as an attribute.  Didn't know there was already one defined.  Guess I didn't read enough on it.